# No log file when using jHiccup on Tomcat application

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to use jHiccup with application which runs on Tomcat7. I have tried to do it in this way:

jHiccup -p tomcat_pid

I didn't receive any error but there was no log neither.

Then I tried to make changes in catalina.sh described here https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup and in posts on jHiccup forum. Tomcat started succesfully but there where no hlog file.  Can sb help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Adrzej,

The hlog file will be generated (be default) in the working directory of the Tomcat process. Did you look around to see if it exists in some other directory than where you expected it to be?

If you want, you can control the placement (and naming) of the log file. E.g. the following line places the log file (with the default naming convention) in /tmp :

jHiccup-2.0.2/jHiccup -l /tmp/hiccup.%date.%pid.hlog -p 40870

-- Gil.

Posted on behalf of Gil Tene by Matt Schuetze.